# Conflict with pip versions

Tags: python, windows, pip, command-prompt

Today I updated pip via command line by

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

to pip 20.2.3, but it seems the latest version is not actually running on my command prompt

[image: Just ommited user name]

I think there is a path conflict, but I don't know how to solve it (I'm a newbie).

Note: I checked PyCharm settings and it's running the latest version (20.2.3).

Comment: Did you notice that your `site-packages` directories are different, meaning that you have two separate Python installations? Use `pip install --upgrade pip` if you want to update the first (Python 3.8 in `C:\program files\python38`) one.

Comment: You can have many Python installations and environments on the same machine. This is what allows eg having both Python2 and Python 3 installed on the same machine. You get one installation if you install Python directly, another if you use Anaconda, another if you use Visual Studio etc. You can switch between them using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) in the command line, or your IDE's environment selection tools. On Windows you can use [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win)

Comment: @Selcuk updated the first one, but now it says "pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper". My biggest problem is that after I updated the first, I can't import any module to my programs. It says 'no module named pygame' (for example).

Comment: That's a different question. Close this one and post it as a new one with relevant details.